# Collaboration on sharepoint

Tags: collaboration

I would like to know how to do the following in Sharepoint?

I wanted to build a page where users from different departments can open an enquiry in sharepoint, and my department will answer those enquiries.

1) User A input their enquiry via a specific form that is created. So that all enquiries are standardized with a specific template.

2) User B will answer the enquiry and send the enquiry back to User A (can it trigger an email to both user A and the respective leader) so that User A is aware the enquiry had been answered?

3) If User A input an enquiry not pertaining to my department, I will like to assign that enquiry to someone else from another department.

4) If the enquiry is still not resolved, user A can continue with that enquiry and put in more comments and send it back to my department, and we will answer accordingly.

All comments needs to be able to recorded so that trail of conversations are there for reference.

Basically, I wanted to replicate the exchange of emails but do it on sharepoint so that people can search using a specific field, and not having duplicate emails.

Thanks.
Eric

Comment: User create an enquiry using form - people answering the enquiry, can it work like a facebook post where people add comments, and if required tag people?

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the best approach will be a proof of concept based on something like [this](https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-create-help-desk-solution-in-sharepoint-out-of-the-box/) or perhaps this [one](https://medium.com/plumsail/how-to-create-helpdesk-on-sharepoint-2013-or-office-365-3d62c43c4de5).

Otherwise plumsail seems to have a good help desk module and there are serveral other solutions in the App store